# Android Studio cannot use debugger - IllegalArguement exception on IDE startup

Tags: android-studio

ADB is running, but the Debugger cannot see any devices.

When Android Studio (v0.1.5) starts up I get the follow Error in the event log:

> 1:17:02 PM IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/local/LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile must not be null: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/local/LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile must not be null

Clicking on the blinking exclamation point in the lower right shows "IDE Fatal Error" window with the following content:

> Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/local/LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile must not be null: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/local/LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile must not be null
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/local/LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile must not be null
>       at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile(LocalFileSystemBase.java)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getManifest(AndroidFacet.java:835)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidResourceFilesListener$1.run(AndroidResourceFilesListener.java:123)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:945)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidResourceFilesListener.notifyFacetInitialized(AndroidResourceFilesListener.java:120)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet$3.run(AndroidFacet.java:661)
>       at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$7.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:286)
>       at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:259)
>       at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$100(StartupManagerImpl.java:52)
>       at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$4.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:183)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWhenSmart(DumbServiceImpl.java:94)
>       at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:177)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$4$2.run(ProjectManagerImpl.java:439)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:708)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:678)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:701)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:526)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:349)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:766)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:195)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:717)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:303)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:297)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:257)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:419)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadAndOpenProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:506)
>       at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openProject(ProjectUtil.java:179)
>       at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManager.doOpenProject(RecentProjectsManager.java:46)
>       at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase$MyAppLifecycleListener.appStarting(RecentProjectsManagerBase.java:324)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:120)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:228)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:219)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:209)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$000(MessageBusImpl.java:43)
>       at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$1.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:131)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.appStarting(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.loadProject(IdeaApplication.java:334)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.access$500(IdeaApplication.java:63)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter$2.run(IdeaApplication.java:301)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:347)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:708)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:678)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:701)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:526)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:349)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a regression in AS 0.1.5.

I had this problem while using a multi module project. The parent module that AS creates when you make  anew project somehow got android and android-gradle facets associated with it.

Removing these in Project Properties > Modules fixed the problem.